# Setting a Cookie For JQuery UI Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, cookies, modal-dialog

We have a JQuery UI Modal Dialog when signing into our internet banking product to display a message. This pops up every single time. Now we want to make this cookie-based so a user only sees this box once until their cookies are cleared. How can I achieve this?

```
<body onLoad="loadPage();" onUnload="unloadPage();">
<script>

$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    //$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );


    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 475,
        width: 550,
        position: 'top',
        modal: true,
        buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });

});


</script>
```

**IMPORTANT MESSAGE FOR ATM/DEBIT CARD HOLDERS**
        Federal Regulations recently changed, which means we are required to get your permission to consider paying overdrafts on your everyday debit transactions.
        
        Please **click here** to find out important information regarding overdraft charges and debit card transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Most simply you can create a cookie to store whether they have seen it or not using the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie):

```
//Set a cookie value
$.cookie('seen', 'yes');

//get the value
var seen = $.cookie('seen');
if(seen == null) { /*have not seen, show modal*/ }

//delete cookie
$.cookie('seen', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When click the close button , cookie will stored
>   as( Cookie name = subscribe_popup_status )  value( shown )

$.cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value");

```
$( '.home_page_popup' ).dialog({ 
   autoOpen: false,
   closeText: "",
   modal: true,
   resizable: false,
   icon: "ui-icon-heart",
   classes: {
       "ui-dialog": "home_page_popup_dialog"
   },
   width: pop_up_width
});

$(".home_page_popup").on("click",".popup_close",function() {

    if ($.cookie('subscribe_popup_status') == null) {
       $.cookie('subscribe_popup_status', 'shown',{ expires: popup_duration });
    }

    $( '.home_page_popup' ).dialog('close');

});
```

Comment: Code is always good, but a description or some comments about what it's doing is helpful as well.

Comment: craigcaulfield - explained in header